# I called js function in form submit...all browsers working fine except IE6

Tags: javascript, function, forms, submit

```
function createTemplate() {
   createformlayers(x, y,z);

   windowResizeRefresh() ;
}
Layers1.text(x,y,z)
{
  //some codes go here
}

function createformlayers(eid)
{
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div'); 
  newdiv.setAttribute("id",eid);
  newdiv.innerhtml ='<form action="javascript:Layers1.text('test',200,200)"></form>';
}

function windowResizeRefresh() {
  for (var n = 0; n < Layers.length; n++) {
    fid = 'form' + n;    
    document.getElementById(fid).submit();
  }
}

<body onload="createTemplate()">
```

Comment: Nothing received any error message... but it working when I give alert function below submit line

Comment: I hope you don't have a form field (or button) name="submit"...

Comment: yes I didn't name any elements "submit"

Comment: What's the form's actions?  What exactly is your Layers object?  What's in the DOM?

Comment: also the forms will be created on fly..

Comment: @Bagan: Just made an edit, please excuse if it changes the purpose of your code. My intent was to make it more legible at first glance. As a side note, in the future please select the code you paste in and press `ctrl+k` to dedicate it as code.

Comment: can you able to see innerhtmal code... I am calling js function like this action ="Layers[n].text(x,y,z)"

Comment: @Brad, wow I see substantially more now.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski: SI,SO. The whole innerHTML approach is sloppy as it is, not going to get much better.

Comment: Are you expecting mytest() to be called when you call submit()?  I didn't realise IE was the only browser than doesn't do that.  In fact, I'm pretty sure it's not the only browser that doesn't do that.

Comment: I think I have to paste entire code here... It's around 2000 lines so I am little hesitate to confuse you all

Comment: I know this is off topic but wouldn't it be easier to use some framework like jQuery? Unless of course you have very tight loading time restrictions...

Comment: the form action js function called in all browsers when submit the form in onload event except IE 6

Comment: hi capsule did get this point "the form action js function called in all browsers when submit the form in onload event except IE 6" also it works in IE6 when place alert function below submit line.

Comment: What's the double asterisk before the action attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure IE to show you a warning whenever it encounters an error.  This warning may give you a clue as to what is failing.  There is also a previous button on the dialog that is useful if there are multiple errors, the previous ones tend to need solving first.

If you have Microsoft Office on the same machine.  You can add/remove shared/misc tools in the Office setup (under add/remove programs) for "Script Debugging".  This is the best debugger you can get for IE6.  (Unless you have MS Visual Studio already, I think this is identical, but I don't have Visual Studio, so I'm not sure how to do that).

With this script debugger, you can open the debugger and set breakpoints and step-through your code and inspect what's going on.  You can also launch the debugger directly from a JavaScript error and inspect the variables/DOM/call stack, etc.

Comment: hello Lee Kowalkowski thanks for your great analysis I don't think this would be a error to trace line by line. the thing the form function gets called when put alert function below document.getElementById(fid).submit(); below this line.

Comment: You can call me 'Lee',  what is alerted that makes it work?  Any arbitrary string?

Comment: simply I tested with alert function whether all the form get submitted properly like this alert(true);

Comment: function windowResizeRefresh() {       fid = 'form' + n;           [n].fontid;     document.getElementById(fid).submit();               }

Comment: Hi lee.. there is my short version of code. please let me know if you can figure outthe problem now.

Comment: Is there a reason you're submitting a form only to execute more JavaScript?  That is, the form's data is going nowhere isn't it?  Your short version of code still doesn't make sense - What is Layers1 for example?  If you can possibly point to or upload a working example, that would be best.

Comment: sure will do. how to make sense onsubmit=return false; in IE6 It doesn't when submit the form... that is the problem. I figuered out.

Comment: onsubmit=return false; prevents the form from being submitted by clicking on a submit button or pressing enter on a form field.  It will not prevent a form being submitted by JavaScript using form.submit().  When using .submit(), the onsubmit event will not fire at all, because you're calling the submit method directly, there is no event.

Comment: nice explain...easty to understand..very close now.. action="javascript:somefunction()" can direct submit will call this function

Comment: It doesn't call in IE6 other browsers calling the function when use direct submit using script

Comment: why do you need to call submit(), why not call somefunction() directly?  I need a few minutes to get hold of IE Sicks to do a basic  test over this.

Comment: call function through submit will save a lot of code because I am creating some image layers using php gd with some attributes like font, size , color... i will manipulate whenever I modify I'll simply call the form to submit. instead of mainting lot of dom nodes... because the image layers will be many

Comment: Are you appending your newDiv element to document.body?  I did a few tests in IE6, and there's nothing fundamental that I can tell other than if you neglect to have a body element, things like that.  So I guess I'm going to need a working example (e.g. works in Firefox, but not IE6)

Comment: thanks for your great time you spare for me... I'll make my script my live tomorrow or tonight...I'll come back here with you... In the mean time I'll try my best...have a great day lee

Comment: yes I am appending all layers to inside of another div that exist in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Doh!  Just realized, you're using the action attribute, which in IE6, may well be limited to something like 512 Characters (including the "javascript:")!!!

Why don't you stick all that in a function?  And have `action="javascript:doAction(); void 0"` or something?

Comment: ummm.. let me try and post you the results if works fine.. coz this is the final bug of my project.. billons thanks goes to your if it solves the problem.

Comment: <body onload="windowresizerefresh()">